# Как сравнивать списки по количеству одинаковых элементов?

Tags: c#

Есть список `List<string>(){"1","2","3"..."1000"};`
Мне нужно из его значений сгенерировать `N`-случайных списков,в котором не было никогда больше 5 одинаковых значений.

Я вручную сформировал несколько таких вариаций, но непонятно как это сделать программно

```
1 2 3 4 5 6  7  8
1 2 3 4 5 9  10 11
1 2 3 4 5 12 13 14
1 2 3 4 5 15 16 17
```

Comment: Постановка задачи допускает много толкований. Какой длины должны быть новые списки? Список из пяти одинаковых чисел удовлетворяет условиям? А список в котором все 1000 чисел встречаются по пять раз?

Comment: И каким образом заголовок связан с самим вопросом?

Comment: @Эникейщик n-cлучайных списков размерностью 8

Comment: Что вызывает затруднения? Берите 8 случайных элементов из исходного списка и начиная с шестого считайте количество элемента в итоговом.